# Android Html to PDF : How to add footer and header?

Tags: android, html, kotlin, pdf, layout

we are trying to create PDF documents from HTML. We have succeeded to transform this HTML with the help of a WebView and a PrintDocumentAdapter but we didn't find out how to add repeating headers and footers on each page.
We would like to add pagination information on the footer : page x on y and an image on the header.

Here is the test html with four pages :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    @page {
      size: 21cm 29.7cm;
      margin: 1.5cm 1.5cm 1.5cm 1.5cm;
    }

    h1 {
      page-break-before: always;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>My book</div>
    <h1>First chapter</h1>
      <p>… </p>
    <h1>Second chapter</h1>
      <p>… </p>
    <h1>Third Chapter</h1>
      <p>… </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the code we use to generate the PDF :

```
package android.print

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor
import android.print.PrintAttributes.Resolution
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback
import android.util.Log
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileNotFoundException
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException


/**
 * Converts HTML to PDF.
 *
 *
 * Can convert only one task at a time, any requests to do more conversions before
 * ending the current task are ignored.
 */
class PdfConverter private constructor() : Runnable {
    private var activity: Activity? = null
    private var urlDoc: String? = null
    private var mPdfFile: File? = null
    private var mPdfPrintAttrs: PrintAttributes? = null
    private var mIsCurrentlyConverting = false
    private var mWebView: WebView? = null
    override fun run() {

        mWebView = WebView(activity!!)
        mWebView!!.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {

                    val documentAdapter = mWebView!!.createPrintDocumentAdapter("doc")
                    documentAdapter.onLayout(
                        null,
                        pdfPrintAttrs,
                        null,
                        object : LayoutResultCallback() {},
                        null
                    )
                    documentAdapter.onWrite(
                        arrayOf<PageRange>(PageRange.ALL_PAGES),
                        outputFileDescriptor,
                        null,
                        object : WriteResultCallback() {
                            override fun onWriteFinished(pages: Array<PageRange>) {
                                destroy()
                            }
                        })
                }
            }
        }
        mWebView!!.settings.allowFileAccess = true;
        mWebView!!.loadUrl(urlDoc!!)


    }

    var pdfPrintAttrs: PrintAttributes?
        get() = if (mPdfPrintAttrs != null) mPdfPrintAttrs else defaultPrintAttrs
        set(printAttrs) {
            mPdfPrintAttrs = printAttrs
        }

    fun convert(activity: Activity, htmlString: String?, file: File?) {
        requireNotNull(htmlString) { "htmlString can't be null" }
        requireNotNull(file) { "file can't be null" }
        if (mIsCurrentlyConverting) return
        this.activity = activity
        urlDoc = saveHtmlTempFile(htmlString)
        mPdfFile = file
        mIsCurrentlyConverting = true
        runOnUiThread(this)
    }

    private val outputFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor?
        private get() {
            try {
                mPdfFile!!.createNewFile()
                return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(
                    mPdfFile,
                    ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_TRUNCATE or ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to open ParcelFileDescriptor", e)
            }
            return null
        }
    private val defaultPrintAttrs: PrintAttributes?
        private get() = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) null else PrintAttributes.Builder()
            .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_GOVT_LETTER)
            .setResolution(Resolution("RESOLUTION_ID", "RESOLUTION_ID", 600, 600))
            .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
            .build()

    private fun runOnUiThread(runnable: Runnable) {
        val handler = Handler(activity!!.mainLooper)
        handler.post(runnable)
    }

    private fun destroy() {
        activity = null
        urlDoc = null
        mPdfFile = null
        mPdfPrintAttrs = null
        mIsCurrentlyConverting = false
        mWebView = null
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "PdfConverter"
        private var sInstance: PdfConverter? = null

        @get:Synchronized
        val instance: PdfConverter?
            get() {
                if (sInstance == null) sInstance = PdfConverter()
                return sInstance
            }
    }

    private fun saveHtmlTempFile(html: String): String? {
        try {
            val outputDir: File = activity!!.cacheDir
            val outputFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".html", outputDir)
            val out = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
            val data = html.toByteArray()
            out.write(data)
            out.close()
            return outputFile.path
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rob this is out of context this is not the point of my question, have you any advice ?

Comment: I'm pointing out that you are not following the HTML specification. It's meant to be helpful. Do you not want to follow HTML standards?

Comment: Of course I want, but I've written this piece of html in 5 minutes just for this question, it's not the final one.